# How to invoke chat on a question/answer where I know the user will need more help

Tags: support

I provided an answer to the following [**question**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19184640/1253219).  The user is asking me questions and needing additional help in troubleshooting.  I know if I provide enough comments eventually I will get a link telling me that I should invite a user to a chat session instead of creating a whole bunch of comments.

I know I will eventually get to that point on this question.  To save us both time, is there a way to open a chat session on a question/answer before that limit hit?

Comment: You can go to [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/) and create a room but the user needs to have 20 rep before they will be able to participate in chat.

Comment: @bluefeet, I knew that, but does the 20 rep count for chat rooms against their own question?